# Pulling old value instead of updated value

Tags: javascript, node.js

index.js (Only the stuff pertaining to this part of the system.)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {GoogleSpreadsheet} = require('google-spreadsheet'); 
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(process.env.SHEET_TOKEN);
const client = new Discord.Client();

const achieveFiles = fs.readdirSync('./achievements').filter(file => file.endsWith('js'));

// Create the Achievements Table
for(const file of achieveFiles){
  const achieve = require(`./achievements/${file}`);
  var key = `${file}`;
  ach_list[key.slice(0, -3)] = achieve;
}

function checkAllAchievement(ply, list2){
 ply.members.cache.forEach(mem => {
  if (mem["id"] === "156963320220352512" || mem["id"] === "202932736984481793"){
     var allRoles = mem["_roles"]
     var keylen = Object.keys(list2).length
     for (var i = 0; i < keylen; i++) {
        var notFound = false;
        var key = Object.keys(list2)[i]

        //get all users roles and check against 1 achievement at a time
        for (var j = 0; j < allRoles.length; j++){
           //Check All Roles Against Achievement Role
           if (allRoles[j] == list2[key].roleID){
              notFound = true
           } 
        } 

       if (!notFound) {
          list2[key].execute(mem, list2[key].roleID, list2[key].name, list2[key].umbrellans, list2[key].description, doc)
          notFound = true
       }
    };
  }
})

setInterval(() => checkAllAchievement(client.guilds.cache.get("the correctnumbershere"), ach_list), 20000)
----------------ReadyPlayerOne.js---------------------

    const Discord = require('discord.js');
var interviewRole = '841576000034570280'
async function checkReadyPlayerOne(user, roleID, achievementName, umbrellans, desc, doc){
  var unlocked = false
  console.log("Running")
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
  const rows = await sheet.getRows();

  var allRoles = user["_roles"]
  // Check all roles for Achievement Role
  for (var i = 0; i < allRoles.length; i++){
      if (allRoles[i] === roleID){
        unlocked = true
      }
    } 
  // If Achievement isnt unlocked then check if it should be
  if(!unlocked){
    for (var i = 0; i < allRoles.length; i++){
      if (allRoles[i] === interviewRole){
        console.log("GIVING U THE ROLE!")
        user.roles.add(roleID)
        user.send("**Congratulations!! You unlocked the achievement '" + achievementName + "'** :partying_face:\n**Achievement Description: " + desc + "**\n**You have received " + umbrellans + " Umbrellans for unlocking this achievement!**");
        rows.forEach(row => {
          if(row.DiscordID === user["id"]){
            console.log(user["id"])
            row.Currency = (parseInt(row.Currency) + parseInt(umbrellans));
            row.save()
          }
        });
      }
    }
  } 
}


module.exports = {
  name: 'Ready Player One!', 
  description: "Receive your Interview Certification.",
  roleID: "844544209830412308",
  umbrellans: 10,
  execute(user, role, name, coin, desc, doc){
    checkReadyPlayerOne(user, role, name, coin, desc, doc);
    //console.log("CALLED FUNCTION")
  }  
}

----------------LivingOnAPrayer.js---------------------

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const interviewRole = '841576000034570280'
const boothRole = '841575999186927636'

var hasInt = false;
var hasBooth = false;

async function checkLivingOnAPrayer(user, roleID, achievementName, umbrellans, desc, doc){
  var unlocked = false
  //console.log("Running")
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
  const rows = await sheet.getRows();

  var allRoles = user["_roles"]
  // Check all roles for Achievement Role
  for (var i = 0; i < allRoles.length; i++){
      if (allRoles[i] == roleID){
        unlocked = true
      }
    } 
  // If Achievement isnt unlocked then check if it should be
  if(!unlocked){
    for (var i = 0; i < allRoles.length; i++){
      //console.log(allRoles[i])
      if (allRoles[i] == interviewRole){
        hasInt = true
      }

      if (allRoles[i] == boothRole){
        console.log(allRoles[i])
        hasBooth = true
      }

    }
    //console.log("booth: " + hasBooth + " int: " + hasInt)
    if (hasBooth && hasInt){
      //console.log("GIVING U THE ROLE!")
      user.roles.add(roleID)
      user.send("**Congratulations!! You unlocked the achievement '" + achievementName + "'** :partying_face:\n**Achievement Description: " + desc + "**\n**You have received " + umbrellans + " Umbrellans for unlocking this achievement!**");
      rows.forEach(row => {
        if(row.DiscordID === user["id"]){
          //console.log(user["id"])
          row.Currency = (parseInt(row.Currency) + parseInt(umbrellans));
          row.save()
        }
      })
    hasBooth = false
    hasInt = false
    } 
  }
}


module.exports = {
  name: 'Living On A Prayer', 
  description: "Receive your Interview Certification & Booth Certification",
  roleID: "844544201563832380",
  umbrellans: 10,
  execute(user, role, name, coin, desc, doc){
    checkLivingOnAPrayer(user, role, name, coin, desc, doc);
    //console.log("CALLED FUNCTION")
  }  
}
```

When it does row.save() it writes it to the google doc.
row.Currency is the value on the doc. It keeps pulling the old currency instead of the new one on each iteration of the loop in index.js. Sometimes it will do both ie gets currency adds 10 and saves. But most of the time it gets the old value adds 10 and saves then gets the old value adds 10 and saves again. I want it to get the value add 10 and save. Then next loop through get the new value add 10 and save.

Comment: It looks to me like you get the rows outside of the loop. So, you don't get the rows after changing the value in each loop, but only once, before the loop starts. That is why the loops all use the "old" value.

Comment: But it sometimes does get the new value.. I have 3 achievements that it iterates through. When I make sure I should get all 3 at once it will add 10 to the documents value while SOMETIMES it adds 20. Never has it added 30(10 per achievment)

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to check the achievements and only save once, when you know how many achievements were achieved in total? Or is it only rarely happening, that multiple achievements are achieved at the same time?

Comment: Its rare that multiple achievements happen at once. None the less it still happens. I am assuming I would need find a way to wait for the execution of the function within the module.execute to finish before continuing the loop in index.js. The const doc is a google api and is a 'live version' of the spreadsheet. Its getting the value off the doc before the prior iteration can finish saving. I think I need to await on the row.save() i just cant figure out how. I have tried that although its possible I did it wrong. Im not good with async.

Comment: It seems to me like multiple checks happen at the same time, so that they get the original value and then the first check adds 10 and saves and then the second does the same, instead of adding to the updated value. The best might be to make sure, that only one check happens at any given time. So, that it is always the newest value, which is gotten with `getRows()`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't know enough about your system to give you a specific answer, but seems like the check functions are already `async`. So, it should be possible to `await` the check, before starting the next one.

Comment: I tried to do the following

(async () => { // start
            list2[key].execute(mem, list2[key].roleID, list2[key].name, list2[key].umbrellans, list2[key].description, doc)
            notFound = true
          })();

This didnt change anything ( Iguess its waiting for the execute to finish which only calls the function. so I added the (async () => { checkLivingOnAPrayer(user, role, name, coin, desc, doc)}) and it just never ran the check function.